# Django: multiple ManyToMany values ALL contained queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

**models.py**

```
class Tag(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,unique=True)

class Product(BaseModel):
    tag_set = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Getting queryset,

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
    Q(tag_set__id__in=[12, 13, 14]),
    Q(is_active=True),
)
```

This queryset would include products of which tag's id is any of 12 or 13 or 14.
I want only products where all tags it has include 12, 13, 14 (**ALL**)

ex) product -- tags(id): 12, 13, 14, 15    (O) 
ex) product -- tags(id): 12, 13, 15    (X)
ex) product -- tags(id): 12    (X)

(Sorry for bad English)

How can I implement this?

Comment: use Q objects like this `filter(Q(tag=tag1) & Q(tag=tag2) & Q(tag=tag3))`

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if that doesn't work @dnit.  The `Q` objects would be applied in conjunction on every line in the outer join and as such filter away everything, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to keep applying filter for all your ids like this,

```
all_products = Product.objects.all()
my_tags = [12, 13, 14]
for tag_id in my_tags:
    all_products = all_products.filter(tag_set__id=tag_id)
```

Comment: It works, but wonder how many query does it make? Would it be kinda inefficient?

Comment: Three, but three simple outer joins, no semi-expensive grouping.  This could be quite efficient. (though I suggest you benchmark different suggested solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Since `Tag.name` is unique, you can filter using a group by and a count. I.e.

```
products = Product.objects.filter(
    Q(tag_set__id__in=[12, 13, 14])), Q(is_active=True)).annotate(
        matching_tags_count=models.Count("tag_set__id").filter(
            matching_tags_count=3)
```

**Update**
In my experience, postgreSQL does not utilize indexes but rather does a full scan when the indexed columns are not matched uniquely.  While I consider this an error, this means that `tag_set__id__in=[...]` is very inefficient for larger tables.  I could speculate this might be different if `Q(tag_set__id=12)|Q(tag_set__id=13)|Q(tag_set__id=14)|` was used instead, but I didn't test it (because I didn't think of it) back when I was Django developer three years ago.  We just ended up doing one query pr id to match.

Comment: I think your solution only include product having tag(12, 13,  14 exactly), which doesn't include product having tag 12, 13, 14, 15 ?

Comment: A product with tags 12, 13, 14 and 15 will also be included, though the tag 15 will be ignored. Only joins matching 12, 13 and 14 are included in the count.  Additional matches are ignored.  If it wasn't so, it would also be easy to say matching_tags_count__gte=3 (but I very much doubt that is the case)

Comment: How many query does it make? It looks like yours only create one query request?

Comment: There is only one query here yes.

Comment: The resulting query structure is slightly more advanced than that of @dnit13 in the other answer.  His is a simple LEFT JOIN repeated three times.  Mine is a LEFT JOIN-GROUP BY executed once.  These two queries might depend on different indexes to execute efficiently.  My query might require more memory than that of dnit13.